# How to use group by function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where each `id` as pk has several `tasks_code`. I am trying to group the relative `tasks_code` to its `id`. When I executed below code, the `group by` function didn't work. How to use group by function if I only need to group by two columns, but select multiple columns to display?

```
Select i.id, p.tasks_code, count(*) 
From problem p 
     Left join id_code i On p.id = i.id
Group by i.id
```

The result returns as:

```
id  tasks_code  count(*)
1      1          1
2      3          1
1      2          1
1      4          1
2      5          1
1      9          1
```

I want it to return the result as:

```
id  count(*)
1    4
2    2
```

Comment: i want it return as id, count(*); 1 4; 2 2

Comment: why couln't I select p.tasks_code?

Comment: the result is A B C, I want just A C (so why didn't you try removing B from query?)...

Comment: "why couldn't I select p.tasks_code? " now that is a question: because `GROUP BY` will produce one row for each UNIQUE COMBINATION of the non-aggregating fields. That's why ID 1 is listed 4 times (because there are 4 unique task id's)

Comment: by the way, you query isn't right and everyone is copying it... if the 2 tables joined by `p.tasks_code = i.id` the first 2 columns of the result could not be different

Comment: Group by function works after I placed the field name inside the count. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Place the field name inside the count and group by id.

```
SELECT
    i.id, 
    count(p.tasks_code) as count_codes
FROM problem p 
LEFT JOIN id_code i 
   ON p.tasks_code = i.id 
GROUP BY i.id


I wanted to also give you a quick test and another way to add to your tool belt.

COUNT(FLD) works but you can use COUNT() OVER() as a window function.  Same result.

-- Simple test
select * into #test
from
(
  values
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 3, 1), 
  (1, 2, 1),
  (1, 4, 1), 
  (2, 5, 1),
  (1, 9, 1)
) as work(id, task, cnt);
go

-- group solution
select id, count(task) as task_cnt
from #test
group by id;


-- windowing solution
select distinct id, count(*) over(partition by id) as task_cnt
from #test

-- Remove temp table
drop table #test;
```

Comment: It works! for the table I am working on, I need 5 column and three joins. Could you give me some hints on how to do it? Sorry I don't have enough point to vote up

Comment: Is this a one time adhoc query?  If so, dump the data to a #LOCALTEMP table.  Then run the select.  For multiple joins, just continue the statement.  Look at Books On-Line (MSDN) FROM clause for more examples.

Comment: "**for the table I am working on, I need 5 column and three joins.**" then ask the real question (as a new question)... but in that new question explain each table (otherwise no-one will know how to create the joins) and provide sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML>>

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>

<script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>



<link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.css" />

<link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">

<tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups">

    <tr class="ng-table-group">

        <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}">

            <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">

                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>

                <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>

            </a>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="user in group.data">

        <td sortable="name" data-title="'Name'">

            {{user.name}}

        </td>

        <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">

            {{user.age}}

        </td>

    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

and This Script>>

Table with grouping

```
Preview
Edit
Code

index.html
script.js
style.css
```

script.js

var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).

controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {

```
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, role: 'Administrator'},

            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Administrator'},

            {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'Administrator'},

            {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'Moderator'},

            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'Moderator'},

            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Moderator'},

            {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'Moderator'},

            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'User'},

            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'}];

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({

    page: 1,            // show first page

    count: 10          // count per page

}, {

    groupBy: 'role',

    total: data.length,

    getData: function($defer, params) {

        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?

                $filter('orderBy')(data, $scope.tableParams.orderBy()) :

                data;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

    }

});
```

})